# How to change AWS console language?

Tags: amazon-web-services

AWS is showing in Spanish. However, translation is not complete and it mixes text, half English half Spanish. I want to have the whole interface in english so it's easy to understand. The only result from googling was how to change S3 language, but I want a solution for all other instances.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can change it from the black bar at the bottom of the console:

[image: Change Language]

Comment: In my case it was already in "English (US)". I just had to switch to any other language, then switch back to English.

Comment: Me too! In my case, you can almost permanently set this by signing out and see the language you are seeing. Reset and sign in and you are set. I guess it is cookie related issue.

Comment: Alisson you are a hero, you hear me? a hero

Answer (score 1):

I also had mixed language console issues (spanish with english), I tried everything (Clearing cache and cookines, incognito mode, resetting language values) and these are the steps that worked for me:

- Choose English language with the previous answers
- Log out
- Open the Sign in window
- Choose the language in the list box located in the bottom right
- Sign in

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AWS has published a new user interface.

In this new user interface, the way to change AWS console language is:

1. Click on your account name in the upper right corner.
2. Click "Settings" to go to "Unified Settings" page.

[image]

3. Pick up the language you want.

[image]